# Sending data from android watch to smart phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os

I have developed two android apps - one in watch and one in smart phone. The watch app can recognize a set of gestures and display them in watch as well as in phone(via bluetooth).

Since the gesture name is sent to the phone app via bluetooth, there is a small delay in displaying the gesture name in the phone. Sometimes it doesn't even show it in the phone app even though the watch displays the recognized gesture correctly. I did this by creating a socket and data is sent through I/O streams.

So I would like to improve the lag and make the gesture name getting displayed in the phone app very fast. What are the methods in which I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest method to send such information from one node to another is using the `MessageApi#sendMessage()`; that has the least overhead and should work well for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I incorporated it and its working perfectly!

Comment: I believe messageapi works only when a mobile phone is connected to one smart watch. I would like to know if there is any other method to send messages when we connect two smart watches to a phone. Could you please help?

Comment: Messages are sent from a node to anothert node, so it can be from any of the watches, for example, to the phone. All you need to know is the nodeId of the phone and the easiest/best way to do that is to use the CapabilityApi.

Comment: HI, could you please explain why it is the fastest method? How is it able to send messages faster than sockets?

Comment: I presume you mean BluetoothSocket and not a TCP socket (since there is no direct wifi connectivity between the two)? First of all, opening such a low level communication channel is a great amount of work; secondly you have to manage the socket yourself, and thirdly, it is not going to give you that much of improvement anyway due to the inherent BT latency, batching, etc. You are welcome to try that and compare.

Comment: I mean Bluetooth socket. I have tried both and I can see fast with no loss messages while using message api. I need some points to justify this and hence I am in search of some details.

Comment: Hi..my doubt might be stupid..but I am bit confused on message api working..I believe in message api, message goes through the data layer and is sent via bluetooth to the receiver side..So it also uses bluetooth..then how is it faster? Could you please explain?

Comment: There might be various reasons, from the implementation being more efficient to having a higher priority when done by the framework. The bottom line is that if MessageApi does what you want, you are encouraged to use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One final query. Apart from android developers website, is there any other source to know more about this topic?

Comment: I am not aware of any.